# How to install the vmath plugin for vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to try out the  vmath.vim plugin which adds up columns of numbers.
It is available at: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx3f0gFZh5Jqc0MtcUstV3BKdTQ/edit?lsrp=1

I copied the vmath.vim file into my ~/.vim/plugin folder.
I also added the following lines in my vimrc

```
vmap <expr> ++ VMATH_YankAndAnalyse()
nmap ++ vip++
```

But using ++ in normal mode or visual mode does not work. Am i supposed to somehow load the plugin before?

Comment: perhaps this doesn't answer your question, but you may want to take a look ;)  https://github.com/sk1418/HowMuch

Comment: Does the script appear at `:scriptnames`? Also, does `:echo loaded_vmath` give you `1`?

Comment: @IngoKarkat positive for both.

Comment: @Kent I put the HowMuch.vim file in my plugin directory. But when I do <Leader>= in visual block mode I get =pattern not found. Am I missing something

Comment: @gforce89 I guess you didn't install it correctly. if you don't use any plugin-manager, you could download the plugin here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=21010 , and extract it to your `~/.vim` . and btw, there is no default mapping `<leader>=`, please read the help doc.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of github repos people created after the talk.

The one I am using is this one: https://github.com/DavidGamba/vim-vmath

It has instructions for pathogen and just by copying the file. If using Vundle use this:

```
Bundle 'nixon/vim-vmath'
vmap <expr>  ++  VMATH_YankAndAnalyse()
nmap         ++  vip++
```